# Is it possible to determine AVL tree balanced or not if instead of height depth is given?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, avl-tree

In question it is given we can use depth only and not height.
(As we know for height we can say if difference between height of left subtree and height of right subtree is is at most one then it will be balanced)
Using depth can we find a way to prove tree balanced or not?
I tried by finding relation between different depth trees
What I got is that

1. If depth max = n
   Then there must be n nodes whose depth is n-1
   But this is just one condition I got.
   It is not sufficient condition
   ( You can ignore my approach and try other thing .As there is no condition on approaching the problem)

Comment: What is the difference between depth and height? I'm not challenging you, I'm trying to understand.

Comment: You can just search on google you will find difference
Basically for height we go from top to bottom
And for depth we go from bottom to top

Answer (score 0):

The principle is the same as with height: use the following logic:

For each node do:

- Get the maximum among the depths of all the nodes in the left subtree. Default (when no left subtree is present) is the current node's depth.
- Get the maximum among the depths of all the nodes in the right subtree. Default (when no right subtree is present) is the current node's depth.
- The difference between these two should not be more than 1.

If you implement this with a post-order traversal through the tree, you can keep track of the maximum depths -- needed in the first two steps -- as you traverse the tree.